# Dynamic screen resolution in VMWare vSphere Client

Tags: virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

I use VMWare vSphere Client to access Windows 7 VM from Windows XP host.

In Virtualbox, with guest additions enabled, in Win-Win machines pair, I had by default the dynamic screen resolution adaptation in the guest (i.e. whenever I resize the window of VM, it internally changes resolution to whatever obscure resolution just to fit the window size, e.g. 1246x517).

Is this achievable with vSphere Client (I have 5.0 version)? I have guest additions, but I only can choose from pre-defined resolutions.

Comment: In fact I was trying to circumvent this problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/79842/how-do-i-get-multiple-displays-to-work-a-vm-within-esxi4-the-option-is-there-bu :)

I managed to launch RDC on my dual display in full screen mode so this in fact solves my problem (and the resolution is just to match those two screens).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're dealing with two different classes of products here. Virtualbox is a **desktop** virtualization system, and ESXi is a **server** virtualization system. As such, the VMware vSphere client is not really meant to be used for heavy day-to-day operations. You'll find performance to be significantly better if you enable remote desktop on the Windows 7 VM and connect via an RDP client.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment (I never used vSphere before so I'm not much familiar with it). Can you recommend some good RDP client, other than default Windows built-in Remote Desktop Connection? (I had really strange issues using it when connecting to VMWare machines some time ago, so I don't think it's very reliable).

Comment: @jakub.g - it's perfectly reliable. If you're having stability problems with the Windows RDP client, there's something else going on.

Comment: "Me too" for ErikA's comment. Any good alternative RDP client that I've ever used was just a wrapper for mstsc.exe anyway.

Comment: In my previous company the problem was when two people were logged in at the same time to the VMWare machine (with the same credentials AFAIR - maybe that was the problem; we've never investigated it really), then the Oracle GUI misbehaved in strange ways when connected from RDP. No such things were happening when we used VMWare Player.

Comment: @jakub.g - Okay, well that's a problem with the Oracle GUI, not the RDP client.

Comment: And likely a problem with using the same creds in two sessions, as well.

Answer (score 0):

When your Virtual Machine has not enough Video Memory, then the available modes will allow for very small screens only, and will cause severe stability problem with RDP also!

Provide it with a sufficient amount of video RAM, and you can choose from many more resolutions, and RDP becomes stable.

But note: this won't solve the original problem with dynamically adjusting the size to VMSphere's window.